# Ways to handle window scroll

Tags: javascript, performance

Let's suppose I have N instances of some class.
Each instance has to do some calculations by window scroll.
There are two ways to do it:
1) Each instance has its own `scroll` handler:

```
var N = 100,
    i;

var FirstWay = function() {
    this.doSomeCalculations = function() {
        // some calculations here
    };

    window.addEventListener( 'scroll', this.doSomeCalculations );
};

for ( i = 0; i < N; i++ ) {
    new FirstWay();
}
```

2) Single scroll handler which runs all instances:

```
var N = 100,
    i,
    instances = [];

var SecondWay = function() {
    this.doSomeCalculations = function() {
        // some calculations here
    };
};

var doCommonCalculations = function() {
    var i;

    for ( i = 0; i < N; i++ ) {
        instances[ i ].doSomeCalculations();
    }
};

for ( i = 0; i < N; i++ ) {
    instances.push( new SecondWay() );
}

window.addEventListener( 'scroll', doCommonCalculations );
```

So, my question is which of this ways is better in terms of performance?

Comment: What do _you_ think is faster and why?

Comment: measure it. thats the only way for you to be sure.

Comment: @Cerbrus I'm not sure, and therefore I ask

Comment: Not even a guess?

Comment: @Cerbrus Non even a guess. Yet another counterquestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rule for this sort of thing is straight-forward: Write the simple code. Does the simple code work well? Good, you're done. No? Diagnose why not, and address that issue. E.g., worry about it *if and when* it becomes a problem.

At a guess, I bet it doesn't matter either way. You have the handlers on a list either way (a list in the browser's event handling, or you rown list). But don't guess, measure *(if needed)*.

Now, if the calculations the handlers needed to do were very complicated and time-consuming **and** they had calculations in common, then there'd be a reason for the complexity of the second way: You could do those calculations once and reuse the result.

Answer (score 1):

In your first example, you're registering an event listener for every single instance.
When that event is triggered, every single instance calls some function.

In your second example, you're registering one event listener.
When that event is triggered, every single instance calls some function.

What would be faster?

1. 10 event handlers calling some function
2. 1 event handler calling some function 10 times?

As far as I'm aware, 2 is faster.

But then again, the difference is pretty much negligible. Unless you're literally registering millions of event handlers, I doubt the difference is even measurable.

Comment: What makes you think there's any significant difference in a modern browser between the event handling mechanism calling the 10 handler functions and the event handling mechanism callilng one handler function that then makes 10 function calls? In the second case, there's an added call.

Comment: :-) Even so, I doubt #2 is faster on modern browsers, though perhaps the browser-to-JavaScript layer boundary is expensive. But like you, I'm sure it doesn't matter.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: I've tweaked that last paragraph a little.

Comment: Fair 'nuff. :-) And you could well be right, given the boundary layer involved.